# Problems Using OpsCenter To Start An AWS EC2 Cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I want to get a Datastax Enterprise cluster working on AWS.

I started by creating a first node with OpsCenter on it.  I used the following Amazon EC2 image to launch this node:

```
image-1439607361.manifest.xml (ami-e715a08c)
```

After the node launched, I went in and configured the OpsCenter basics.  I configured the `/etc/default/dse` with:

```
EXTRA_CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/mx4j-tools.jar"
HADOOP_ENABLED=0
CFS_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
SOLR_ENABLED=0
SPARK_ENABLED=0
CFS_ENABLED=0
```

In `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`, I used the 172.11.11.11 internal ip address for the seed, the listen address, the broadcast address, the rpc address and the broadcast rpc address.

I left the snitch as `com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch`

I pointed `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password` and fixed the permissions to it.

I set up a JMX user and password.

I stopped the services datastax-agent, dse and opscenterd and re-started them.

nodetool status showed the node as up.

Then, I went to the opscenter url at port 8888.

I selected "Manage An Existing Cluster".  Entered the seed node.  Entered the credentials, and the OpsCenter dashboard showed and just hung.  Back on the node, I got the following in the `/var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log`:

```
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [cluster3]  INFO: Done loading persisted scheduled job descriptions
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [cluster3]  INFO: Agent for ip 172.11.11.11 is version '5.2.4'
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [cluster3] ERROR: Agent for 172.11.11.11 was unable to complete operation (http://172.11.11.11:61621/load-stomp-conf?): No cassandra connections available
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [cluster3]  INFO: Automatic agent setup failed for (unknown ip): No cassandra connections available (172.11.11.11)
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 []  INFO: Starting to update agents' configuration
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [cluster3]  INFO: OpsCenter starting up.
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 [] DEBUG: Persisting config file /etc/opscenter/clusters/cluster3.conf
2016-01-28 22:28:57+0000 []  INFO: Finished starting new cluster services for cluster3
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [] DEBUG: Average opscenterd CPU usage: 1.61%, memory usage: 53 MB
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [cluster3] DEBUG: keyspace type all are {'all': [u'system', u'system_traces', u'dse_system', u'system_auth', u'dse_auth', u'OpsCenter', u'cfs'], 'system_with_auth': [u'system', u'system_traces', u'dse_system', u'system_auth', u'dse_auth', u'dse_security']}
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [] DEBUG: Keyspace collecting status for: [u'dse_perf']
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [cluster3] DEBUG: [control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [cluster3] DEBUG: [control connection] Finished fetching ring info
2016-01-28 22:29:05+0000 [cluster3] DEBUG: [control connection] Rebuilding token map due to topology changes
2016-01-28 22:29:26+0000 [cluster3] DEBUG: [control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
2016-01-28 22:29:26+0000 [] DEBUG: Error during pending deferred: [Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py:1141:unwindGenerator
/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py:1020:_inlineCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Cluster.py:1354:collectNodeList
/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py:1141:unwindGenerator
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py:1020:_inlineCallbacks
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/CassandraService.py:326:getTokenList
]
2016-01-28 22:29:26+0000 [cluster3] ERROR: There was an error while collecting the node list: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Cluster.py", line 1042, in updateNodeList
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
```

I got the following in `/var/log/opscenter/repair_service/cluster3.log`:

```
2016-01-28 22:53:56+0000 [cluster3] ERROR: The state of the following nodes could not be determined, most likely due to agents on those nodes not being properly connected: [<Node 172.11.11.11='1304142645335128783'>]
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: So this looks like a subnet debug message, is this being created for a VPC?

Comment: Anything in ```/var/log/datastax-agent/``` logs? There should be an ```address.yaml``` for agent as well, which would be helpful to include. Looks like OpsCenter is starting fine but it cant connect to the agents.

Comment: /var/log/datastax-agent/agent.log is saying this:

Comment: WARN [Initialization] 2016-01-29 20:15:05,458 Error when trying to match our local token: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
    INFO [Initialization] 2016-01-29 20:15:05,458 Sleeping for 20s before trying to determine IP over JMX again

Comment: /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml is present, but empty.

Comment: Yes, the node is running in an AWS EC2 VPC.